# Django ORM FieldError in query of some calculation

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

This is my model for Purchase:

```
class Purchase(models.Model):
    amount = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=6,
        decimal_places=2,
        default=0.00
    )
    entry_by = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='ledger_entry_by',
    )
```

and this is my model of Consume:

```
class Consume(models.Model):
    amount = models.FloatField(default=1)
    consumed_by = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='consume_entry_for',
    )
```

I am trying to find out user who how much consumed more than he purchases and who how much consumed less than he purchases

this is my query for this:

```
purchase_vs_consume = User.objects.annotate(
            purchase_vs_consume=Coalesce(Sum('ledger_entry_for__amount'), Value(0))  - Coalesce(Sum('consume_entry_for__amount'), Value(0))
        )
```

It throws following error:

```
Expression contains mixed types: DecimalField, FloatField. You must set output_field
```

later my query was it:

```
purchase_vs_consume = User.objects.annotate(
            purchase_vs_consume=Coalesce(Sum('ledger_entry_for__amount'), Value(0))  - Coalesce(Sum('consume_entry_for__amount'), Value(0)), output_field=FloatField()
        )
```

it throws the following error:

```
QuerySet.annotate() received non-expression(s): <django.db.models.fields.FloatField>.
```

I am not getting what's wrong with this.

**I want:**

**for example, A user Purchased 500 USD and he consumed 550 USD, that is mean, he needs to pay another 50 USD**

**another user purchased 440 USD but he consumed 400 USD, that is mean, you will get refund 40 USD.**

**another user example can be: a user didn't purchase anything but he consumed 300 USD, so he needs to pay 300 USD**

I am trying to achieve above this calculation but it fires me an error.

Can anyone help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
User.objects.annotate(purchase_vs_consume=Coalesce(Sum('ledger_entry_by__amount'), Value(0), output_field=FloatField()) - Coalesce(Sum('consume_entry_for__amount'), Value(0), output_field=FloatField())).values('purchase_vs_consume')
```

Please update your query. You are using two different types of the field in each model and doing calculations. So while you aggregate inside, you must pass an `output_field` so that calculation happens on the same data types.
There is no need to pass output_field in case of consume_entry_for, the query will work without that as the field is already a FloatField.